# parse.com What's your authentication strategy on existing user accounts?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

**Context**

I am using Parse.com as my backend for a mobile app. I use Facebook login only for now.

Assuming the user has logged in with Facebook and now has an account created on Parse already.

**Question**

Every time the user opens the app, should I do a check if his account is still valid by using `PFUser.currentUser().become()`? Or should I use the cached `PFUser.currentUser()`?

I have found out that if I delete the user account in the Parse backend, if I don't do a `become()`, the `PFUser.currentUser()` is still valid, even if the account does not exist anymore.

What is the best practice?

Comment: Are you planning to delete users in the backend?

Comment: @Wain I won't be doing it behind their back, but the users have the ability to delete their account. And they could be using the app from multiple devices.

Comment: I am currently using the become(). I noticed that when the user uses the app on multiple devices, their session often is invalidated and they need to reconnect via Facebook. Is this the normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally better to add a column to the user such as 'disabled', and when the app starts you can `refresh` the user, check that flag and display a message to the user and logout. That, from a user point of view, is similar to using `become` (at least as long as you check and notify the user).

So, you should do something if you're going to be removing or disabling users in the background. The main question is wether you fully delete the account or just delete the contents but leave the (empty) user in the system as a record.

Comment: Is there a benefit or disadvantage to using `become` in terms of performance. I understand that using `refresh` and `become` are two different scenarios (from the developer's point of view)

Comment: And to answer your question, I am thinking more of "disabling" the user and not completely remove him/her from the database.